# Time Picker not showing time in 12Hr format in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement wherein I have to change all the time pickers and selected time formats to 12hr irrespective of the time format of the device.
This issue is specific to Android. It's working fine in iOS.
I'm using a custom time renderer for both.

Here is what I'm doing:

In XAML:

```
<customElements:CustomTimePicker x:Name="TimePickerName" Time="{Binding time}">
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_TimePickerTapped" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
<TimePicker.Format>hh:mm tt</TimePicker.Format>
```

In Xaml.cs:

```
void Handle_TimePickerTapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if(TimePickerName.IsFocused)
                {
                    TimePickerName.Unfocus();
                }
                if(!TimePickerName.IsFocused)
                { 
                TimePickerName.Focus();
                }
                TimePickerName.Format = "hh:mm tt";
            });
    }
```

In View Model: (fetching time for current item from DB)

```
 time = (TimeSpan)DBHelper.GetTime(CurrentItem).TimeOfDay;
```

In Custom Renderer i.e CustomTimePicker class:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.TextSize = 14;
        Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
    }


 public void OnTimeSet(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        var time = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
        this.Element.SetValue(Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker.TimeProperty, time);
        var dateTime = new DateTime(time.Ticks);
        var formattedTime = dateTime.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        this.Control.Text = formattedTime;
    }
```

I want the time picker in 12hr format also the selected time should come in 12hr format irrespective of the time format of the phone.
Post selection due to `OnTimeSet` method I'm fo able to convert it to 12hr, but for the first time, it's taking the time format setting of the device.

Comment: I am pretty sure the timepicker is by default in 12hr format in xamarin forms

Comment: @G.hakim, even if the device format is 24 hrs?

Comment: Yeah of course is it not working for you like that?

Comment: no, it's showing 24hr clock and formats if the device setting is 24hr

Answer (score 1):

There is supposed to be a is24HourView..

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.TimePicker.SetIs24HourView/p/Java.Lang.Boolean/

You've got that covered?

--- edit, well.. ---

Two clocks, one in 12-hour format, showing at present 12:24 AM.

```
<TimePicker x:Name="TimePicker12">
     <TimePicker.Format>hh:mm tt</TimePicker.Format>
</TimePicker>
```

Another in 24-hours, both on the same page, this one showing 00:24.

```
<TimePicker x:Name="TimePicker24">
     <TimePicker.Format>HH:mm</TimePicker.Format>
</TimePicker>
```

Code-behind:

```
TimePicker12.Time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(DateTime.Now.Minute);
TimePicker24.Time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

Comment: That's not working for me. Also, it can only be used in OnTimeSet method which gets called after the first time it's opened.

Comment: I am binding the time property of the timepicker from ViewModel by a database call so cannot bind time from xaml.cs for the first time.

Comment: <TimePicker.Format> works on Android only, not on iOS